# Water in my central vacuuming system?

Tags: central-vacuum

We have a central vacuum system that was installed in our 4 year old new build. It works perfectly but about 6 months ago we found water in the canister. We assumed our cleaners had accidentally dropped the end of the hose into the pool. We hired an industrial vacuum to suck out all the water (several gallons). All fixed and working well. Then yesterday found water again? Definitely not an accident this time. My husband thinks there is a leak and somehow water is getting into the system but surely we would lose suction? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you live in an area of high humidity? Is the canister located in an area where it is in a cool air conditioned space? It is feasible that the vac system may be sucking in hot humid air and that over time the cool canister causes the moisture to condense out of what ever air is left in there when you shut it off. Over a period of time this could build up in a collection of water a few drops at a time.

Comment: Hi Michael, no the opposite; our canister is located in a basement pool plant room which is humid. The rest of the house is not air conditioned and is not humid as we live in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

We have a problem like this. Our central vacuum unit is located in our detached garage with a pipe going from the garage to the house underground (it's about 20 feet from the house to the garage). We found that the roots of some trees cracked the pipe and water was seeping into the pipe and getting sucked into the canister. Is any of your pipe underground?